# python cubes analytical workspace list_cubes() fails

Tags: python, olap-cube, cubes

The current analytical workspace code seems to have some import error.

I tried this ..

```
from cubes import Workspace
workspace = Workspace(config="slicer.ini")
workspace.import_model("model.json")
workspace.list_cubes()
```

And I get this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-f80f0974af47> in <module>()
----> 1 workspace.list_cubes()

/home/anand/.virtualenvs/cubes/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cubes/workspace.pyc in list_cubes(self, identity)
    535         """
    536 
--> 537         all_cubes = self.namespace.list_cubes(recursive=True)
    538 
    539         if self.authorizer:

/home/anand/.virtualenvs/cubes/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cubes/namespace.pyc in list_cubes(self, recursive)
    112                 name = cube["name"]
    113                 if name in cube_names:
--> 114                     raise ModelError("Duplicate cube '%s'" % name)
    115                 cube_names.add(name)
    116 

NameError: global name 'ModelError' is not defined
```

I'm using the 1.0.1 version.
And have tried the latest master from github, but that fails even at the

`from cubes import Workspace`